# Invalid connection string attribute in Django

Tags: python, sql-server, django, web, odbc

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "mssql",
        "NAME": " DJANGOOSQL",
        "USER": "sa",
        "PASSWORD": "Daytek00",
        "HOST": "LAPTOP-KBFP4DGE",
        "PORT": "",
        "OPTIONS": {"driver": "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server", 
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: please post the full traceback.

Comment: You should also specify the port to which the database is "listening".

Comment: send us more info if possible.